# Seeking recommendation for a IT ticket management app

Tags: appexchange, servicecloud, support, service, queue

I'm comparing apps in appexchange for IT ticket management. I've found 'BMC Remedyforce - IT Help Desk' pretty good.

Have any of you used any other apps which were better?

(The other option is to use cases and solutions out of the box/ customize them.)

Comment: Unless your requirements are extreme, I don't understand why you wouldn't use Cases.  If you need a richer self service environment, you can also use Knowledge.  When making these decisions, a good question to ask is:  What are you doing so differently that the standard feature doesn't address?  Should you perhaps alter the way you do things to reflect out of the box functionality?

Comment: Hi Prabhat, this question doesn't currently fit well as on-topic to this site. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
It comes across as largely subjective, every response could be equally valid. It might be more appropriate on a general discussion forum such as the [Salesforce Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/) or the [Force.com Discussion Boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/).

Comment: I will try it out on the other communities you mentioned, instead of here. Thank you for pointing it out Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'BMC Remedyforce - IT Help Desk' is good but it involves configuration which usually means hiring in guys from Remedyforce or partners... It is ITIL compliant which is great if it is what your are looking for.

After that you have Stome Cobra or ITinvolve... Don't know what they are like...

The other options is to use Cases with recordtypes or there is a few free apps there(DIY option) which is grand if you are looking for quick...

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be a best answer for this question as you would know what is best for your company and what are you planning to build and extend its functionality.

But here is one-- http://www.slideshare.net/InternetCreations/case-management-apps-webinar